# When I ran command react-native run-ios . Why the app doesn't exist?

Tags: xcode, react-native

When I ran command `react-native run-ios` . Why my app doesn't exist?

and Simulator always shows IphoneX when I try to change another device.

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 6"
```

[image]

but when I opened Project via x-code and run. It works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

close both the react packager (the terminal window that is launched when you `run-ios`) and the simulator. Then run

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 6"
```

from your react native project directory. This should open the packager in another terminal, open the sim, install the app on the sim and open the app.

Comment: It has still run the iPhone X and the app doesn't exist.